# Getting error when the contact form be submitted

Tags: php, contact-form

Getting error when the contact form should be submitted.

> Undefined index: HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH in C:\xampp\htdocs\dishadwellings\dishaparkwest\contact.php on line 7
>       {"type":"error","text":"Sorry Request must be Ajax POST"}

Here is the HTML FORM code:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="POST">  
                        <input type="text" name="do-input-name" id="do-input-name" placeholder="Name">
                        <input type="email" name="do-input-email" id="do-input-email" placeholder="Email">
                        <input type="text" name="do-input-web" id="do-input-web" placeholder="Web">

                        <textarea name="do-input-message" id="do-input-message" cols="30" rows="10" class="do-input-message" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>

                        <button type="submit" id="do-submit-btn" class="do-btn-round-solid">SEND</button>
                    </form>
```

Here is the code for the contact form: I could not rectify the error. Kindly do the favour to solve this issue

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_email       = "abc@gmail.com"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here

    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
            'type'=>'error', 
            'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
        ));
        die($output); //exit script outputting json data
    } 

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $name       = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email      = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message    = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }

    //email body
    $message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n-".$name."\r\nEmail : ".$email;

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$name.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

    if(!$send_mail)
    {
        //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .' Thank you for your email'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: also post your code..

Comment: Give here ajax code which is doing this submit thing

Comment: can you `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']."<br> requested with ".strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])`

Comment: same error i'm getting when i do echo

Answer (score 0):

Try your if condition as follow:

```
//check if its an ajax request, exit if not
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest')) {

    $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
        'type'=>'error', 
        'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
    ));
    die($output); //exit script outputting json data
}
```

The next thing is, you are submitting form via normal HTML form and you are trying to check that submit data OR send email only if its ajax submit. which is not truth and so it not works.

To make your code working, either submit your form data via ajax OR remove this if condition shown above.

Your post code

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_email       = "abc@gmail.com"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here


    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $name       = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email      = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message    = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $subject = "Test email";
    $user_name = "Sharnya";

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
        $output = 'Name is too short or empty!';
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        $output = 'Please enter a valid email!';
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
        $output = 'Too short message! Please enter something.';
        die($output);
    }

    //email body
    $message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n-".$name."\r\nEmail : ".$email;

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$name.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

    if(!$send_mail)
    {
        //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
        $output = 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.';
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = 'Hi '.$user_name .' Thank you for your email';
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

HTML form code:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">  
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                        <input type="text" name="web" id="web" placeholder="Web">

                        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" class="message" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>

                        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="do-btn-round-solid">SEND</button>
                    </form>
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132163/discussion-on-answer-by-rupal-getting-error-when-the-contact-form-be-submitted).

Comment: Thanks @BhargavRao I was searching for same. but I dont know from where I can create chat room. can you please show me how do I?

Comment: As the OP has not yet earned the chat privilege (20 reputation), you cannot create a chat room. Only moderators can provide write access to those users.